# Navigation View Menu Items like Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play, android-navigationview

How do I achieve navigation view like Google Play Store with some padding in the sub items. I want to apply this using `NavigationView`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think this one library help you, not completely same as play store but some thing near to play store https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign